# euclidean distance and similarity

Tags: excel, similarity, euclidean-distance

My teacher has given me these set of questions as homework and I don't know if I'm understanding it right.

The following customers have rated a number of DVD's as shown in the table. Calculate the similarity figures for these customers using the Euclidean distance method. Then, using the similarity figure as a weighting factor, calculate the weighted average scores for each movie.

[image]

1. Which other customer is most similar to Dave?
2. What is the similarity score for that customer?
3. Which movie does this scheme recommend for Dave?
4. What is the weighted rating for that movie?

Now, to my understanding I need to use **coordinates** to find the Euclidean distance since the formula is:

[image]

And according to my teacher the Similarity formula is:

[image]

Do I use the coordinates by row or column to calculate the Euclidean?

Do I need to use another formula to calculate the weighted rating?

OR do I need to use the formula both ways (row and column)?

I'm really trying to wrap my head around this.
Am I in the right direction or off completely?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a mathematics related question, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are comparing customers, you will be comparing the columns, not the rows.

Excel has a function `SUMXMY2(array_x, array_y)` which computes the square sum of two arrays (e.g. `SUMXMY2(DVD_Table[Alice],DVD_Table[Bob])`). You can simply take the square root of this to get the Euclidean distance between two customers.

It is not clear to me how the weighted ratings are calculated.

Unless you have further Excel or programming questions related to this, you'd do better posting at https://math.stackexchange.com.